# Fixed scale snap increment

Tags: snapping, scale

How do I lock the scale snap increment to +/- a specific value?

While scaling a object using snap to increment, the increment is 10% of the current scale. For example, with a object with scale [0.1, 1.0, 1.0], while scaling in the x-direction the snap will be +/- 0.01 (first picture) and while scaling in the y-direction the snap will be +/- 0.1 (second picture). Instead, I want it to always be +/- the same value.

I will note: Holding shift only changes the scale increment to 1% of the current scale, it doesn't lock it to a value. I've already set the display grid's subdivisions (View -> Properties -> Display) to 1, so that's not the issue. I could scale and snap the object's vertices while in edit mode, but I specifically want to change it's scale value, not its vertices.

[image: x direction scaling]

[image: y direction scaling]